# Extract PDF pages from document, but keep them searchable

Tags: windows, pdf, software-rec

I want to extract pages 1-50 from a PDF document into another PDF document. I realize windows has a print > save as PDF or Microsoft Prints PDF. Both of these render a giant image, and the text is no longer searchable.

I can't really find a solution without downloading paid software like Adobe (nope). Is there any way this can be accomplished without some third party paid software? This seems like an extremely basic task that Windows does not really support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use [PDFSAM Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF_Split_and_Merge):

> PDFsam Basic or PDF Split and Merge is a free and open-source cross-platform desktop application to split, merge, extract pages, rotate and mix PDF documents.

-> https://pdfsam.org/pdf-extract-pages/

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I hate that such simple tasks on Windows has to feel so hacky

Answer (score 1):

You can try by installing [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) software and then with command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=50 -sOutputFile=OUTPUT.pdf ORIGINAL.pdf
```

you will create new file with first 50 pages of `ORIGINAL.pdf`

For more commands/tune you can read the [manual](https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Readme.htm) of ghostscript

Comment: Thanks for adding the links.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the free
[PDF24 Tools](https://www.pdf24.org/en/).
I have used it for such work and it does the job.

You could use the "Extract PDF pages" tool to extract your pages.
Alternatively, you could use the "Remove PDF pages" tool to
remove pages 51 and beyond.

As the tool operates and conserves the original PDF source code
itself, and does not convert or create anything, it should work
better (unless the PDF is password-protected).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PDFtk from [PDF Labs](https://www.pdflabs.com/)

To extract the pages 1-50 from input.pdf and create output.pdf try the following:

`pdftk A=input.pdf cat A1-50 output output.pdf`

There is even a Windows GUI.